# Почему не ставится фоновое изображение на страницу

Tags: html, css, spring, spring-mvc

style.css

```
html { 
    background-image: url(images/home-bg.jpg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    position: relative;
    height: 100%;
}
```

Index.jsp

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8" isELIgnored="false"%>
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">

<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
        <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <link href="../css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

        <style><%@include file="/WEB-INF/css/style.css"%></style>


        <title>Home Page</title>

    </head>

         <body>

         <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">KazNIC</a>
            </div>
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li class="active"><a href="#">Главная</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Наш университет</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Электронный журнал</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Студенты</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Фотогалерея</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Карьера</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Контакты</a></li>
            </ul>
            <form class="navbar-form navbar-left" action="/action_page.php">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search" name="search">
                </div>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Поиск</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    </nav>

    <div class="container">

    </div>

    <div class="container">

    </div>


    <div class="bg">
        <div class ="pokaz">
            <form action="allStudents" method="post">
                 <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Показать всех студентов">
            </form>

        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Расположение файлов

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вынес из папки
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Вам наверно не сказали что все что находит в папке WEB-INF закрыто с браузера. Переместите стили на уровень папки с картинками.

Comment: Вот такая ошибка -  /WEB-INF/views/index.jsp (line: [15], column: [16]) File [/WEB-INF/css/style.css] not found

Comment: об этом я и говорю. Вынесите стили из папки веб-инф

Comment: Посмотрите я правил вопрос(правильно же вынес)

Comment: вы вынесли, а пусть в jsp исправили?

Comment: Вот такой должен же быть путь -  <style><%@include file="/css/style.css"%></style>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуй вставить картинку через

```
<img src='images/home-bg.jpg'>
~~
Если не получиться значит проблема в пути. Или может быть проблема в картинке, попробуй таким же способом вставить другую картинку.
<img src='images/...'>
Ты так же можешь добавить класс и манипулировать картинкой добавлять позиционирование и тд
<img class='img' src='images/home-bg.jpg'>
<style>
html { 
    background-image: url(images/home-bg.jpg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    position: relative;
    height: 100%;
}
</style>
```